# Swift - How do I add an observer to my own function?

Tags: swift, function, selector

I am just using this code as an example:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(WebView1.rotated(_:)), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

I know what the **self** and the **selector** parts do of this method, but I am not sure what it is called to add this to my own function. 
Is this something someone could explain or show me a reference to it.

Basically I what I want to achieve is to put a function in a .swift file but I need to pass those 2 parameters to it.

I hope this example will clarify what I mean:

```
//When I call the function
something(self, #selector(ViewControllerName))

//What I want to create
func something(what do I need here?, what do I need here?) {

}
```

So I have a function in a separate swift file that I need to access from multiple other swift files - that is why I want to pass on the selector into the function.

At the moment, I just have the same function within these swift files, but I am trying to refactor it a bit by doing it this way.